# Create Sqlitedb from Android.App.Application

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a Android.App.Application which tries to create a DB.  I'm using the SQLite db example code. It works great if I use it inside an Activity. When I try to create the exact same thing inside my Android.App.Application it crashes. I've got no clue why.

When I'm calling this from an activity:

```
public class Manager extends Activity{  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    fbdbhelper = new FishingBuddyOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());   
    db = fbdbhelper.getTbfw().getReadableDatabase();
    }
```

A sqlite db is created (/data/data/com.fishingbuddy/databases/)

When done from an Android.App.Application it fails:

```
public class FishingManager extends Application{    
public FishingManager() {       
    fbdbhelper = new FishingBuddyOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());   
    db = fbdbhelper.getTbfw().getReadableDatabase();
    }
```

> 09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to >instantiate application com.fishingbuddy.logic.FishingManager: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4550)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:153)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at com.fishingbuddy.logic.FishingManager.(FishingManager.java:26)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:983)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
>   09-22 21:19:18.386: E/AndroidRuntime(21881):    ... 11 more

I'm using a Application because I'm using the singleton pattern for my FishingManager. It all worked great until I started the final part, saving all my data to an SQLite db.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `fbdbhelper.getTbfw()` doing?

Comment: Gets the db object which includes the definition for the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm calling this from an activity:

It will crash with a `SuperNotCalledException`.

> When done from an Android.App.Application it fails

Even if you deleted the two lines of code here, it will crash, with a `SuperNotCalledException`.

Please call `super.onCreate()` in `onCreate()` of an `Activity` (or `Application`) before doing much of anything else.

> I'm using a Application because I'm using the singleton pattern for my FishingManager.

You do not need an `Application` subclass to have a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`. You just need a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper` that you lazy-initialize on first use.

Comment: The Singleton pattern is applied on the manager which includes the db. So no db Singleton is used.

Comment: @flitjes: That is fine, but you still do not need a subclass of `Application` to have a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`, "manager", or anything else.

Comment: Ok that still doesn't answere the question. I forgot to add the super calls in the activity. But why won't it work within an Application. I don't want an SQLiteOpenHelper Singleton explicit, it just came together after deciding to add the sqlite db.

Comment: @flitjes: Well, you missed `super.onCreate()` in your `Application` subclass as well. Beyond that, rather than call `getApplicationContext()`, use `this`, as you *are* the `Application` `Context`, and `getApplicationContext()` is where you are crashing.

Comment: Ahh Ok, Thnx I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare a content provider in the manifest file like given in this [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#contentprovider)